# Xcode 14.3.1 Update Causing Error: library not found for -lrealm-monorepo

Tags: ios, xcode

I updated Xcode to Version 14.3.1 and now I'm facing this error:

ld: library not found for -lrealm-monorepo
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I tried everything outthere but I'm not sure why nothing works.